# Create a fixed size 3 dimensional array of type string

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a fixed size 3 dimensional array in Swift with datatype of string like this:

```
var 3dArray:[[[String]]] = [[[50]],[[50]],[[50]]]
```

But it is giving error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected element type string

Comment: `50` is an integer, not a string. And variable names cannot start with a digit.

Answer (score 1):

From your question title you are trying to create 3d array with datatype `[[[String]]]` and in your question detail you are assigning it an `Int` value which is not possible in swift. That's why you are getting an error. Because your `3dArray` object is expecting a `String` values

Either you can assign `String` values this way:

```
var yourArr: [[[String]]] = [[["50"]],[["50"]],[["50"]]]
```

Or if you want to make `Int` array you can do it this way:

```
var yourArr: [[[Int]]] = [[[50]],[[50]],[[50]]]
```

**Note:**

As @Martin R suggested variable names cannot start with a digit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no typical way of creating multidimensional arrays in Swift.

But, you can create an array which will contain only `String` arrays and then append 3 different `String` arrays. Please find the code below:

```
var array = [[String]]()

array.append([String]())
array.append([String]())
array.append([String]())
```

At the end your array will be looking this way:

```
[[], [], []]
```

Or you can just create same array this way:

```
var array:[[String]] = [["50"],["50"],["50"]]
```

But keep in mind, `"50"` are strings which are content of those arrays and not their size.

If you want to have a fixed-size array, then you have to use some third party solutions like [this one](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Fixed%20Size%20Array).

Comment: NSMutableArray is not a fixed-size array.

Comment: Yeap, my bad. Edited the answer.